# Check if app sending Intent has a custom permission

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I have an app which Broadcast receiver accept Intents from external apps,
I defined 2 permissions:

1. `com.example.myapp.myProvider.permission.CREATE_SECURE_TABLE`
2. `com.example.myapp.myProvider.permission.WRITE_SECURE_TABLE`

When I receive an Intent from an external app I want to check if it has:

- The first permission in case it wants to create a table
- The second permission in case it wants to write a table

Note that the app that creates tables is not the one that writes them, so an app that creates tables doesn't need the second permission and vice versa.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define 2 separate `BroadcastReceiver`s, where one requires a create permission,  and the other requires a write permission (using `android:permission` attribute).

Comment: Thanks, i defined 2 intent filters but how can i assign the required permission inside the filter? can i use the attribute android:permission=""?

Comment: @user3774592 Sorry, I fixed my answer, it appears there is no way to specify multiple permissions on a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) 
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    return false;
}
```

Instead of `Manifest.permission.INTERNET` place your permission

Answer (score 0):

You can't check it, but Android does it for you. Depends on property [`android:protectionLevel`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) of your custom `<permission>`, Android will ensure external app has granted permission before it can call your app's component.